# Difference between Adobe Media Encoder CS4, CS5 and CS5.5

Tags: adobe-cs5, adobe-cs4, adobe-cs3

What is the main difference between Adobe Media Encoder CS4, CS5 and CS5.5?

```
- Do they encode differently? 
- Is Adobe Media Encoder CS5.5 better than its predecessor (CS4 and CS5)? 
- Do they have distinct hardware requirements?
```

Comment: ... Look at here: http://blogs.adobe.com/premiereprotraining/2011/04/adobe-media-encoder-cs5-5-whats-new-and-changed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract from [blogs.adobe.com](http://blogs.adobe.com/premiereprotraining/2011/04/adobe-media-encoder-cs5-5-whats-new-and-changed.html) - provided by [bZezzz](https://superuser.com/users/112928/bzezzz)

> - Added encoding presets for iPad devices and other tablet devices.
> - Improved encoding presets for YouTube, Vimeo, and other popular output formats.
> - You can now import image sequences into Adobe Media Encoder.
> - Watch folder features are much improved, including ability to add the same watch folder to the encoding queue multiple times and assign
>     multiple sets of encoding settings for multiple output types from the
>     same source. Adding a watch folder is now as easy as dragging a folder
>     into the Watch Folders pane.
> - The Start Queue Automatically When Idle For preference is off by default. (Yay!)
> - A new checkbox, Auto-Encode Watch Folders, gives you the ability to decide whether items in a watch folder are automatically encoded as
>     soon as they appear, as opposed to waiting until the encoding queue is
>     started.
> - Added context menus to many items, so that common commands are available by right-clicking (Windows) or Control-clicking (Mac OS)
>     many items. An especially handy pair of such menu items are Reveal
>     Source File and Reveal Output File, which show the location of the
>     respective file in the Finder or Windows Explorer.
> - Added ability to drag a sequence from the Adobe Premiere Pro Project panel or a composition from the After Effects Project panel into Adobe
>     Media Encoder to add it to the encoding queue. You can also begin the
>     process of importing by double-clicking in an empty area of the
>     encoding queue pane.
> - RED (R3D) source settings can be accessed using File > Source Settings, with improved RED support like that in After Effects CS5.5
>     and Adobe Premiere Pro CS5.5, including new color science support
>     (REDcolor2, REDgamma2, REDlogFilm, etc.) and better curves and levels
>     UI.
> - A chime sounds when the encoding queue is done processing, like in After Effects.
> - The trial versions of Adobe Premiere Pro CS5.5 and After Effects CS5.5 include all codecs included with the full versions, so users of
>     the trial version will be able to import any file that can be imported
>     using in the full version, as well as being able to encode using any
>     codec that can be used in the full version. Because Adobe Media
>     Encoder receives its codecs from the client applications, this change
>     expands the functionality of the Adobe Media Encoder CS5.5 trial
>     version, too.